# How can I propose that a certain group of comments should be deleted?

Tags: discussion, comments

A mod made a comment under my question that I thought was a little too personal about me, contains no useful information, is likely to be interpreted in more than one way, and is likely to mislead people about my character in a negative way. Perhaps I shouldn't have responded, but I did respond and required two comments to do so. I strongly feel that this use of comments is not in the spirit of what the comments section is for, and I think it would be best for the question if all three of these comments were deleted. What is the correct way to raise this issue?

Comment: You can delete your own comments yourself.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Delete your own comments yourself.
2. Flag the remaining comment as "It's no longer needed." if it contains no useful information.